# Array defined from class construct returns 1 in functions

Tags: php, arrays, class, variables, this

I have this code here:

```
class Class_name extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->user = array("value"=>"test");
    }
    public function index() {
        print_r($this>user);
    }
}
```

The problem is $this->user returns as 1 instead of the actual array.
I have tried other variable names with no luck.

What am I doing wrong?

Peter

Comment: Because `$this->user` is array itself, or only 1 array key exist

Comment: What do you mean? I $this->user used in other constructs and it works fine.

Comment: print_r($this>user); - you have an error when you call user variable

Comment: @Dmitriy.Net eagle eye, missing `-` mark there. Nice catch

Comment: It's a monday thing..... I'm not usually like this hehe, cheers guys!

Comment: Bring us 2 tons of coffee :D

Comment: does $this>user even compile? I'm surprised :P

Comment: It returns 1, not sure why, but it's obviously a valid variable. Don't know what it does.

Comment: @briosheje It's php: `$this > user` -> variable greater then constant

Comment: But the constant doesn't exist, so shouldn't I get an error?

Comment: Surprisingly, eclipse is not letting me compile if I write $this>user, but I think it's related to the editor itself. $this>user is indeed valid, and should return 1, since it's true, right?

Comment: In fact, I switched errors off, I will switch it on now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just have a little typo here:

```
print_r($this>user);
```

change it to:

```
print_r($this->user);
```

Comment: You are a legend, I feel like an idiot. I'm blaming Monday haha!

Comment: @PeterStuart Monday, hmm, accepted, it's Mondays fault. Have a nice day :D

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `->` in the line `print_r($this>user)`

 Here is the edited script:

```
class Class_name extends CI_Controller {

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->user = array("value"=>"test");
    }
    public function index() {
        print_r($this->user);
    }
}
```

Comment: Live savior answer, keep up!

Answer (score 1):

You've got a typo.

```
print_r($this>user);
```

should be:

```
print_r($this->user);
```

This works fine:

```
class foo {
    function __construct()
    {
        $this->user = array("value"=>"test");
    }
    public function index() {
        print_r($this->user);
    }
}
$foo= new foo();
$foo->index();
# Results in:
# Array
# (
#     [value] => test
# )
```

As an interesting aside, this is because in PHP, objects are 'greater' than strings:

```
var_dump(new stdClass > 'foo');
# bool(true)
```

Comment: Notice he is using `extends CI_Controller` so thats instance is unnecessary

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function index() {
        print_r($this->user);
    }
```